# Steam trade bot на java

Tags: java, steam-web-api

Здравствуйте, есть задача написать steam trade bot, который будет обмениваться вещами с клиентами на сайте, возможно ли это сделать на java, и посоветуйте библиотеку для этого, steam web API (исходя из гуглинга) не поможет?

Comment: Ботов же вроде как запретили сами стим. Steam web api - поможет

Comment: Есть решение на C# https://github.com/Jessecar96/SteamDesktopAuthenticator

Comment: @markov это находил, к сожалению не знаком с шарпом, но спасибо

Comment: @AndrewBystrov  на счёт запрета не слышал, но я и не особо следил так что возможно вы правы

Comment: Запрет вроде есть, но никто не запрещает полностью скопировать мобильный аутентификатор. @newakkoff ну на самом деле языки похожи, можно влиться немного, зато там готовый апп: который сам обновляет сессию. На яве обновление сессии без фичи аутентификатора не сделать, ещё вариант - плагин на хром писать

Comment: @markov я вас понял, спасибо за совет, попробуем!

Comment: @Qwertiy может наоборот? Тот вопрос позже задан.

Comment: @Denis, нет, там есть ответ и активный спрашивающий.